# Bullzip Access to MYSQL Error on Arabic Text Encoding

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2010, converters, arabic

I am using Bullzip Access to MYSQL converter to convert Access db tables to MYSQL script.

My problem is the Arabic text in the MYSQL script does not displayed correctly (i.e ?§U„U…?¹U„U…).

But in the Access table the arabic text displayed correctly.

Bullzip Access to MYSQL v5.1.0.232 
MS Access 2010 
MYSQL 5.5.20

Please can anyone help to resolve this problem.

Comment: This is a crucial bug. Can anyone help me please !!!

Comment: Anybody Here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

HOW TO PROPERLY DISPLAY THE ARABIC LETTERS USING A HTML/PHP PAGE AND MySQL :

[SƲMARAßƲS.com]

STEP #1:

Choosing the right character set for the MySQL database in Wampserver®:

1. Create a new table.
2. Select "utf8_bin" as character set.
3. Save.

STEP #2:

1. Open the "results page" (page which will be used for the request) and find the following line in the "Code area":

   mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyTable);
2. Copy/paste the two following lines immediately below the line:

   mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1256");
   mysql_query("set characer set cp1256");

The result will be:

```
mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyTable);
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1256");
mysql_query("set characer set cp1256");
```

1. Give to the "Results page" de following character set "Windows-1256" just like that :
2. Save.

Source of this Tutorial found on sumarabus.com (many Tutorials on the Arabic language and the creation do web pages) - direct link to the Tutorial (with screenshots) at the end of the response.

Other Tutorials available:
- Inserting date in Arabic with Hijri/Gregorian calendar.
- Creating a virtual Arabic keyboard.
- etc...

Ma3a assalama,
Mister Arabic.

Link to sumarabus.com :

```
www.sumarabus.com/2_Dynamic/6_Computer_Tutorials/Tutorials/Wampserver/Wampserver_2.php
```

Comment: Thanks in advance Mister Arabic, my problem not in the view (read) the database in html/php. just i need to inject the arabic data from access db to MYSQL db using Bullzip converter.